# Unable to implement audio equalizer circuit in LTspice

Tags: audio, ltspice, simulation

I am new to the subject and have been given a project on implementing an audio equalizer circuit. I have followed the circuit of a predecessor on this site, but I am unable to get the results and I am studying the theory to understand what went wrong. How does the circuit work, and what went wrong in mine?

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to link to the "predecessor on this site".

Comment: 1) *How does the circuit work* You propose this circuit so why don't **you** tell us how it **should** work (what you expect it to do if it was working perfectly). 2) I'll gibe my standard advise for all beginners: did you check the DC operating point? Run a .OP simulation and check that all the DC voltages are correct. 3) You should learn how to work with an AC simulation as well. An AC simulation only works if there is at least one source with an AC = 1 statement.

Comment: You should have had a warning when you tried to run the simulation, the error log should have popped up complaining about *No AC stimulus found*, along with a solution to what you're supposed to do. I'm surprised to see you don't even mention this. Also, if this is an audio equalizer then why are you simulating from ***1 mHz*** to ***10 MHz***?

Answer (score 1):

The sinewave has no amplitude listed inside the brackets. Try 100mV peak.

The 885 capacitors do not say if they are 885 Farads, microfarads, nanofarads or picofarads.
The curve will be a notch filter because you have lowpass filters feeding highpass filters. Reverse them and you will have bandpass filters.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem: there's no AC stimulus to run an `.AC` analysis. The source works with `SIN()` just fine, except it will be a zero value.

Comment: The .AC settings are on the right side of the schematic that has its parts too far apart. I copied his simulation with the same results, plus a warning that there is no input signal voltage. it works fine with an input signal of 100mV.

Comment: If you're referring to the `.AC` card then that is useless without a stimulus (the `AC 1` part in the source). *That* is what was missing and the reason OP sees that flat -390 dB line. When you say "*a signal of 100 mV*", that's missing the point of an `.AC` simulation, since that's what OP wants (in his picure there's only one simulation card). The solution is to replace `SIN()` with `AC 1`, that's it. And what you're saying about reversing the order of lp and hp makes absolutely no sense: convolution is commutative. Only changing the values of fp for each will change the result.

Comment: The filters are not active, instead they are simple first-order passive filters at the inputs of buffer opamps.

Comment: Yes, so? Are you saying that, because of that, the rules of convolution change? For example, if a lowpass with f_lp=10k and a highpass with f_hp=100, are in series, lp 1st, hp 2nd, the output will be a notch? And if you reverse the order the output will be a bandpass? And if those two filters would not be passive, the output will be a bandpass (or bandstop) irrespective of their order? Is this what you're saying?